# Resource failing to load with yepnope.js

Tags: javascript, resources, yepnope

Right, I've just started using yepnope.js for resource loading... I like the idea but it's not behaving itself at the moment.

I use the following code to load a JavaScript resource:

```
<script>
    yepnope('/resource.php?js&file=path/to/file.js');
</script>
```

Now resource.php is a resource handling script in our app, it does caching etc.

The problem I'm having is yepnope appears to fetch the file, but it looks like nothing is loading. The resource appears in Chrome's web tools:

[image]

However notice the icon isn't the usual JS one, even though it's defintely returning as `text/javascript`, I wonder whether this might be because yepnope uses `<img />` tags for resource loading.

It's not like I'm getting nothing at all back, here are the headers it's recieved:

[image]

I've set the `expires` header to something well in the future as I was told yepnope needs this, still no joy.

What am I missing? There appears to be no response and the JavaScript just desn't execute, not even a simple echo. If I open that same resource in a new tab it shows the content perfectly.